# Erlang EUnit test module that depends on a library application

Tags: erlang, rebar, eunit

I have a medium-sized release with a handful of applications.  I recently refactored some common functionality out into a library application within the release.  This made my EUnit tests fail with `undef` messages whenever testing anything that required the library application.

The set up is something like this:

```
% In apps/utils/src/utils.erl
-module(utils).

-export([foo/0]).

foo() -> "OH HAI".
```

Then

```
% In apps/some_app/src/some_app.erl
-module(some_app).

-export([bar/0]).

bar() -> io:format("foo: ~s~n", [utils:foo()]).

% unit tests for bar()
```

Then the unit tests for `some_app:bar()` fail.  I'm running them with `rebar eunit skip_deps=true`.  I'm using `skip_deps=true` because my release uses some 3rd party applications (SQL, etc).

I assume that the tests start failing because EUnit is invoking the app under test without its dependencies?  Is there any way to fix this?  I have configured the .app file to explicitly declare the dependency.  It works fine in the release, and it's been deployed for about a day now with no problem, but I'll feel a lot better if I can get the tests to pass again :)

(I could use a mocking app to stub out `utils:foo/0`, and I can see where that would be ideal idiomatically, but that seems like overkill in this case because `utils:foo/0` (read: it's real-world counterpart) does some really simple stuff.)

Comment: I think this has nothing to do with EUnit itself, but how Rebar is running the tests. Either because it simply doesn't compile the other applications when you use skip_deps, or because it doesn't add them to the Erlang code path even if they have been compiled previously.

Comment: I think I need to dig into the rebar source to figure this one out :/  I *think* the `skip_deps` flag just skips the unit tests in the `deps` directory (which is being used for 3rd-party stuff).

Comment: As far as I can tell from looking at the rebar source, `skip_deps` just tells rebar to skip applications in the `deps` directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get this to work by doing `rebar compile eunit skip_deps=true`.

The key is to have the `compile` in there and I have no idea why.  I'm guessing that the compile step gets all of the modules into memory.  I'd love to hear a good explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could have one of your applications load the utility by including it in the application portion of you .app file, as in:

```
{application,yourapp
         [{description,"A description"},
          {vsn,"1.0.0"},
          {modules,[mod1, mod2, utils]},
           SNIP
```

or in some other way add it to the path of the erlang node... maybe using the -pa flag on starting the node.

Comment: The module is part of another application.  It is listed as a dependency in the `applications` section of the .app file.  The `modules` section is for modules introduced by that app, so not appropriate.  I tried it anyways, though, and it still didn't work.